# signed vs unsigned interpretation

Tags: assembly

Just wanted to know something about signed vs unsigned interpretation. Am I right if I say that if a number is unsigned integers it's value is calculated normally by converting the binary into decimal..but when it comes to signed integers, the sign bit(msb) is noted first and then the binary value is calculated using 2's complement ; the value calculated is the real value with the sign noted.

Am I right or missing something?

Comment: does the signed case i asked applies only to signed negative numbers?

Comment: In the case of conversion to "decimal with an optional sign-prefix", yes it works that way. The sign is looked at separately, and the absolute value (which in this context *does* exist for int.minvalue, because it's unsigned) is converted to decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. When converting a *signed integer* represented in *2's complement* form into a *decimal* number, this is how you would do it. And *2's complement* is how Intel processors store and do math with signed integers.

<sub>NOTE: But this answer is *not* about how Intel machines represent signed integers. It is general.</sub>

The technique you use to convert to decimal really depends on the representation used by the hardware.

A hardware designer may choose to store a signed number as:

1. Sign-Magnitude (1 bit specifies sign, the others specify the magnitude, no complement)
2. 1's complement (where, the 8-bit `11111111` represents a `-0`, and `00000000` a `+0`)
3. 2's complement (popular in general purpose hardware, like Intel)
4. ... (there are other ways too. Read more in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations))

And we humans need to use the corresponding 'conversion' when reading those in our preferred, decimal form.

e.g. If you were designing hardware that mostly does multiplications, storing signed integers in sign-magnitude form would make some sense. You just multiply the signs and magnitudes separately. On the other hand 2's complement numbers are [a little unwieldy to multiply, but not much](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Multiplication).

Of course, 2's complement is the way most hardware (almost all the general purpose CPUs today) stores signed numbers. This makes additions a piece of cake.

Comment: You don't have to do 2's complement multiplication the lame way though - the lower half is just a regular multiplication and there are some tricks for the upper half (I forgot what the tricks are, exactly. really how often do you need them outside of class..). Anyway, there are better ways than sign-magnitude to store integers optimized for multiplication (RNS for example)

Comment: @harold - Right. My intention was to give a simple explanation while maintaining that there are different representations available. One way to multiply 2's complement nicely is the 'Modified Baugh-Wooley multiplier'. I recently built one of those as a drop in replacement for the LEON3 single cycle multiplier :)

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is the most typical way to convert signed binary integers into human-readable strings with decimal digits.

However, this is not the only way. You can convert your 2's complement negative 3-bit value 111 first into "7" and then subtract "8" from it and arrive to "-1".